# Is K3b cd/dvd software compatible with 20.04?

Tags: dvd

I have used this program for years on 18.04, but after updating to 20.04, it doesn't work.

After writing a DVD, it seems to close the disk but takes a long time.
At the beginning of the Verify operation, it takes a long time and ultimately fails verify on Sector 0.
After that, dvd cannot be read at all.

Based on some comments I've read, it seems K3b is not compatible with 20.04, though it's still listed in Software Center and Ubuntu Package Search. Also I couldn't find anything indicating that K3b is actively supported.

So I wanted to ask here in case I'm missing something. Or some other solution or options for writing dvds?

Comment: I don't know what your problems are; but your issues maybe related to your DVD writer getting old & thus failing. I rarely write *optical* media; but I've had to replace four DVD writers in my last six writes. My *stats* are heavily influenced by the replacements used are not new drives (*being salvaged from retired boxes*) but a lot of *optical* media is now getting old & components don't live forever.  I've found no differences writing media from any release (*up to 22.04 anyway*)

Comment: Don't forget `k3b` is a universe package (ie. *Ubuntu community supported*), thus it's 3 years of *guaranteed* support ends this month for 20.04 or *focal*.  Whilst it's true that is received a bug fix for a prior release outside of the 3 years; that was only days after the 3 years & the bug filed that was fixed, was filed during the 3 years of support for 'universe'.  It's supported now on *focal* until and during April 2023.

Comment: Hardware wears out in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problems are; but your issues maybe related to your DVD writer getting old & thus failing. I rarely write *optical* media; but I've had to replace four DVD writers in my last six writes. My *stats* are heavily influenced by the replacements used are not new drives (*being salvaged from retired boxes*) but a lot of *optical* media is now getting old & components don't live forever.

I've found no differences writing media from any release (*up to 22.04 anyway; having not written anything since then I believe though I do recall writing during the alpha stage of kinetic/22.10; which includes `k3b` & `xfburn`; but particularly `k3b` as it was supported by Lubuntu [until we dropped it](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/dropping-trojita-k3b-fcitx-from-lubuntu-jammy-22-04-seed/3044)*)

Answer (score 0):

`k3b` is in the `universe` repository on 20.04 which is an official Ubuntu repository. So to answer your question, **YES, k3b is definitely and explicitly compatible with Ubuntu 20.04**.

Here's a link to packages matching k3b and 20.04 on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=k3b&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all).

To use this software you need to enable the `universe` repository, then install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install k3b
```